# Using post object inside ACF repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields on my website.

I have a repeater field called anime_par, with sub_field called animateur. Sub field animateur is a post-object.

I’m using this inside a loop in my page, a loop that displays posts from a category inside a custom post type.

What I’m trying to do is to display the post name and post link of the animateur selection inside my page.

Here is the code I’m using but it’s not working, it displays the permalink of my current page, not the one selected in the custom field.

```
<?php while(has_sub_field('anime_par')): ?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink('the_sub_field("animateur")'); ?>"><?php echo get_title('the_sub_field("animateur")'); ?></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any suggestions to make this work?

thanks for your help,

Comment: I think your syntax is a little off inside the get_permalink and get_title functions. You want to pass the post id. Right now you're passing a string. Maybe try get_permalink(get_the_ID(the_sub_field('animateur')));

Answer (score 14):

This method is working for me, per the repeater and post object docs on ACF. You've got to set up the post object inside of the repeater loop.

I added in your field names, and some completely optional html to show the structure.

Hope it helps.

```
<!-- Start Repeater -->
<?php if( have_rows('anime_par')): // check for repeater fields ?>

<div class="a-container">

    <?php while ( have_rows('anime_par')) : the_row(); // loop through the repeater fields ?>

    <?php // set up post object
        $post_object = get_sub_field('animateur');
        if( $post_object ) :
        $post = $post_object;
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>

    <article class="your-post"> 

        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php // whatever post stuff you want goes here ?>

    </article>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>

    <?php endif; ?> 

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
<!-- End Repeater -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`the_sub_field` doesn't work without `has_sub_field`
What you have to do it is use loop with `has_sub_field` as it said in the documenration http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_sub_field/

or you can use `get_field('repeater_sluf')` like that

```
$rows = get_field('repeater_field_name' ); // get all the rows
$first_row = $rows[0]; // get the first row
$first_row_image = $first_row['sub_field_name' ]; // get the sub field value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(get_field('favourite_design_quarters', 'user_'.$current_user->ID)): ?>


<?php while(has_sub_field('favourite_design_quarters', 'user_'.$current_user->ID)): 
$company = get_sub_field('company_name');
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $company->ID ), 'package-thumbnail' ); 
?>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?=$company->post_title;?>" /></td>
                    <td><?=$company->ID;?></td>
                    <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$company->post_content;?></td>
                    <td><?=$company->post_date;?></td>
                    <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, you should probably include some prose text to explain why it solves the asker's problem.